# Change current thread culture in UWP applications

Tags: c#, uwp, currentculture

In the `UWP` application, I want to change the culture of a new created thread like this:

```
private  void btnRun_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TestMethod));
    newThread.Start();
}

private void TestMethod()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
}
```

Setting `CurrentCulture` property in the thread method body cause all application threads culture (also `UI` thread) be change.

This problem occur only in `UWP` applications and its OK in other types of .net projects.

Comment: There are a *lot* of duplicates for this question, hard to pick the best.  Let's take you [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22565), keep an eye on it for future improvements.

Comment: Did you finally find any good solution / workaround? I'm breaking my brain with this issue.

Comment: No good solution, i switch between cultures by some conditions in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I am using UWP in Xamarin.Forms so my workaround is as follows:

inside OnLauncehd method in App.xaml.cs I wrote the following code:

```
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
            ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "en-GB";
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
```

In case it doesn't work, I am doing it in MainPage.xaml.cs too:

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {


            this.Loaded += (sender, args) => {

                SetEnGbCulture();

            };
        }

        public void SetEnGbCulture()
        {
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
            ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "en-GB";
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().Reset();
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();

        }
    }
```